# How could I make WebBrowser.Navigate analog for bytes array, instead of URL?

Tags: c#, load, browser, arrays, document

I planning to load PDF files into it, but I can't save those to disk. PDFs exist only as byte arrays in my program.

For text data I can use something like this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html>page content</html>";
```

But PDF is not text, so I need some other way, but can't find any.

I tried this:

```
byte[] file_content = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Metafalica\\Documents\\DatabaseSQLLanguageRzheutskaya.pdf");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file_content);
ms.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
```

But getting this:
[image]

Comment: Did you try with `webBrowser1.DocumentStream` Property?.

Comment: For unknown reason it doesn't load PDFs this way. It loads those as text, but not as PDF via Adobe / Foxit plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to load and render a PDF via `webBrowser.DocumentStream`. What happens behind the scene is that an instance of [MSHTML Document Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets created and initialized with the supplied stream. You could possibly load an image (which MIME type is recognized by MSHTML), but not a PDF. On the other hand, when `webBrowser.Navigate` is used, an instance of Adobe Acrobat Reader PDF Document gets created, rather than MSHTML.

Comment: Is it possible to override Navigate method to load from byte array? I don't know what happens after navigate, but this should be simple... Just replace file reading code somewhere, but where? :(

Comment: To my knowledge, the only way to do it would be to implement a [custom pluggable protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(v=vs.85).aspx), which is quite non-trivial and still would require a custom URL, something like `mypdf://<unique-stream-id>`. You might be better off hosting Acrobat Reader ActiveX control (`AcroPDF.dll`) directly instead of `WebBrowser`. IIRC, it supports `IPersistStream` so you should be able to load it without a URL.

Comment: Depending on your goals, maybe you could just save your PDF bytes to a temp file and navigate `WebBrowser` to it?

Comment: Sadly no, whole purpose to keep file safe from copying. It exist as encrypted bytes built-in program.